# Remove all local history entries in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a StatefulWidget that adds to its Navigator's local history via `ModalRoute.of(context).addLocalHistoryEntry()`. When certain changes occur, I want to reset the widget's state and clear any local history that it added. I don't see any API on `ModalRoute` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to check the current route before the first build and then use `Navigator.popUntil()` to remove all local history entries at once.

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  initialRoute ??= ModalRoute.of(context);
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}

void reset() {
  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route == initialRoute);
}
```

Note however if another widget uses local history entries on the same ModalRoute, those local history entries will also be removed. A more thorough solution would require access to the topmost route or at least the length of local history entries on the current ModalRoute.